# Why is Jean Rollin's "Le Viol du Vampire" Called this way? (The Rape of the Vampire)

Tags: title, the-rape-of-the-vampire

I have not seen the entire movie, but from the snippets I have seen and the Wikipedia and other plot summaries, the movie does contain eroticism and violence but doesn't seem to involve rape.

Why such a title then?

Comment: A case of contextual lost in translation. It happens, there are many movies that have odd titles when translated into other languages. The pure translation doesn't come with the context often culturally necessary to understand the title.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ - What is the context?

Comment: Think of it as word equivalency, such as violated versus raped, both can be used to refer to the same event but differ in their context. In translations such subtle equivalency or context can get lost when a word is translate verbatim. However, it seems that according to @crow it might actually be relevant to the content as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia synopsis for the film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Viol_du_Vampire#The_Rape_of_the_Vampire) seems to indicate that the film is named for the events which allegedly lead up to the first short:

> Four sisters living in an old château are **convinced that they are vampires**. **One believes she was raped** by the villagers years before, and is blind; another is afraid of sunlight, and they all react violently to crucifixes.

And in the end:

> Thomas asks one of the sisters to bite him to prove her wrong and discovers she is, in fact, a vampire.

Which would indicate it's probably true.

Comment: Agreed. The "Viol du Vampire" is taken in two distinct senses. First is: it was the initial rape by the villagers that turned the sister(s) from them. So that was a *description* of an event from the past. (The lady (who became the vampire) was raped, her virginity taken.) Then there is the title as a 'title of an *event* that happened now.' At the end, Thomas' mortality was taken from him, by the vampire. The *event* is the current rape _by_ the vampire. So "Viol du Vampire" fits both the event of the origin and of the end.